# DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE in Insert

Tags: php

I have a form where I want to make token expire feature via `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` when I insert it.

I known how to add when update but don't known how I add this script when insert.

How I add `Date_Add(Now(); internal 5 minute` at the palace of `tokenExpire`

```
  $con->query("INSERT INTO users  (Name,Email_ID,tokenExpire) VALUE('$name','$email','DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE');");
```

But it's not working.. please help..

Comment: Try removing the quotes and the semi-colon, like so:
`$con->query("INSERT INTO users (Name,Email_ID,tokenExpire) VALUE('$name','$email',DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no quotes around `DATE_ADD`:

```
$con->query("INSERT INTO users (Name,Email_ID,tokenExpire)
             VALUES ('$name','$email', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");
```

Also your code may be susceptible to SQL injection attack, you'd better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: could you post the script related my question. How I make it secure as experience or practical. I real your link but it look like tough. Might if you post script based my question it would be better. Help to make it secure. Pls post.